# How i get column while compare json encoded data in select query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, jsonencoder

The `users` is json encoded

```
$agent_id = $request->get('user');

$model = AgentPermission::select('module_category')->where('users', 'like', '%$agent_id%')->get();
```

I want to to show "module category" where json encoded data is present in "users" column 
if it is working the whole code is working fine 
because when i use this

```
$model = AgentPermission::select('module_category')->where('users', 'like', '%"10"%')->get();  it is working perfect
```

Comment: Is there a reason you storing users in a field rather than in a separate table?

Comment: so ```users``` fileld is ```id of users``` am in right

Answer (score 0):

The comparison should be inside double quotes, not single quotes

```
$model = AgentPermission::select('module_category')->where('users', 'like', "%$agent_id%")->get();
```

since PHP injects variables only when using double quotes.

The alternative is:

```
$model = AgentPermission::select('module_category')->where('users', 'like', '%' . $agent_id . '%')->get();
```

Comment: @NabeelAli  if it answered your question, please mark it as resolved.